# Short story about an astronomer who has horrible luck - maybe by Poul Anderson

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think this short story was by Poul Anderson (or maybe Frederic Pohl?) and that it appeared in the early to mid-1970s. It was not an Analog-type story, so that leaves the other magazines published in that period, like F&SF or Galaxy. The main character is an astronomer who begins life with high hopes but ends up failing in everything he does. I can't remember just why or how, but his observatory becomes a front for organized crime. He dies at the end; his body is found on the toilet, the first victim of a nasty new disease that will forevermore bear his name - the only thing he will ever be remembered for. Pretty grim stuff.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

"[Shaffery Among the Immortals](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?40953)" by Fred Pohl

This [review](https://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf1042) contains various matching elements:

> A funny yarn about one Jeremy Shaffery, an
> astronomer who idolizes Einstein and his methods and who wants to
> achieve immortal fame by doing something just as famous. The problem
> is that he is not built for this (“The Einstein method, which he had
> studied assiduously over many years, was to make a pretty theory and
> then see if, by any chance, observations of events in the real world
> seemed to confirm it. Shaffery greatly approved of that method. It
> just didn't seem to work out for him.”).

> In the end, he achieves non-mathematical fame in an unwitting
> pandemic he causes which destroys most of the world's population…

Comment: "The Einstein method ... make a *pretty* theory and then see if, *by any chance*, observations of events in the real world seemed to confirm it" That *not* being the Einstein Method might have been part of his problem.

Comment: Yes, it's pretty clear that Shaffery isn't as knowledgeable as he thinks.